# web_components instead of shadow_dom for angular-dart

Tags: dart, angular-dart, web-component, shadow-dom

Since [shadow_dom](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shadow_dom) is officially deprecated and suffer from some painful bugs. i wonder if its safe to use web_components as suggested in the pub page. while dart-angular [tutorial](https://angulardart.org/tutorial/09-ch07-deploying-your-app.html) still use shadow_dom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely change to `web_components` `shadow_dom` causes lot of troubles especially on FireFox (when you build to JavaScript)

see also: https://github.com/angular/angular.dart.tutorial/issues/119

Comment: Thanks ! thats was very helpful, i wish the angular-dart tutorial get updated soon to reflect this, so that newbies in angular-dart like me doesn't get stuck in compatibility issues. best regards

Comment: They worked very hard to add new features and get it polished for 1.0. There are always a lot of things that should have been done already :-(. Of course, you are right but you should also be aware that you are using bleeding edge tech...